# Conversion Stats in Facebook's Ads API - cumulative or specific to time interval?

Tags: api, facebook-ads-api

For the [Conversion Stats](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/conversionstatistics/) attribution values in the Ads API (ie, post_click_1d, post_click_7d, post_click_28d, post_imp_1d, post_imp_7d, post_imp_28d), are the values cumulative or are they capturing specific conversions relative to the time interval?

If cumulative, do they reset per day?
Is there any difference between account, campaign and ad-level stats calls?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your the value you pass to aggregate_days. By default, its 0 which is the total number of conversion. If you set it to 1, it would be aggregated daily, likewise, 7 for weekly

Refer to the Aggregation Window part of the documentation.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/conversionstatistics/

There's definitely difference between account, campaign and ad-level stats. It depends on which level of the stats you need, whether you want all the ad-groups within a campaign, account, or just a few particular ad-group.